# plotting a scatter plot with wide range data R

Tags: r, plot, scatter-plot

I uploaded a csv file to R studio and am trying to plot two columns. The first one shows the **number of likes**, and the second shows the **number of shares**.  I want to show the relationship between the number of shares when people actually like a post.

The problem is my likes count starts from 1 to 1 million, and the shares count start from 5 to 37000.

sample of my dataset (both columns are of class `factor`)

```
topMedia$likes_count
   [1] 61   120  271  140  59   498  241  117  124  124  225  117  186  101 
  [15] 118  134  152  136  153  124  100  77   98   77   88   48   58   66  


topMedia$shares_count
   [1] 12   171  NULL 23   34   108  430  NULL NULL NULL 283  NULL NULL 57  
  [15] NULL NULL NULL 68   105  NULL NULL 7    10   45   103  22   75   16
```

When I use this code to plot a scatter plot. It looks messy.

`plot(as.numeric(topMedia$shares_count),as.numeric(topMedia$likes_count))`

[image]

I tried using other libraries

```
library(hexbin)

cols = colorRampPalette(c("#fee6ce", "#fd8d3c", "#e6550d", "#a63603"))
plot(hexbin(as.numeric(topMedia$shares_count), as.numeric(topMedia$likes_count), xbins = 40), colorcut = seq(0,1,length=20),
     colramp = function(n) cols(20), legend = FALSE,xlab = 'share count', ylab = 'like count')
```

but I get a similar result even with colours

[image]

what would be a better way to show the relationship between those values?
Thanks .

Comment: `heatmap` in base R or `geom_bin2d` in `ggplot2` might be useful here. See here for more strategies: https://www.displayr.com/what-is-overplotting/  or   https://www.data-to-viz.com/caveat/overplotting.html

Comment: The problem seems to be the large number of data points. Try using `smoothScatter` or `hexbin`. A couple of examples here: https://cddt.nz/visualising-big-data-in-R.html

Comment: I suspect you have factor data here, and your conversion with as.numeric is converting the values of the factor and not the levels. That might explain the near-uniform distribution you are seeing, whereas I would have expected a strong linear correlation between the two measures. Try replacing `as.numeric(topMedia$shares_count)` with `as.numeric(as.character(topMedia$shares_count))` and same with the other measure.

Comment: @JonSpring it looks better after adding as.character! but it have changed the numbers on the axises. Any idea why? thank you for your help.

Comment: @cddt I have updated my post with my attempt of hexbin. It didn't change the plot. Thanks

Comment: (Please correct me, more experienced people!)   Factors are a data type in R which store categories ("levels") as integers (their "values"). So Jan-Feb-Mar might be stored as 1-2-3, or Apple-Cucumber-Strawberry-Orange as 1-2-3-4. In this case, your data came in with levels 5234-43489-483 stored with the values 1-2-3. That's why you had an even distribution of shares and likes. What you wanted were the levels (the "5234" part, instead of the "1" part), which you can extract by converting to character... And you want those as numbers, by converting the character to numeric. (!)

Comment: I see, thank you Jon.

Comment: There is an option to avoid this when you make a data frame. In many (most?) use cases you want "stringsAsFactors = FALSE", but it is TRUE by default, making anything that looks like character data into a factor. This trips people up a lot if they were trying to load numbers.

Comment: @leena if you can add the result of `str(topMedia)`, it should be clear whether @JonSpring's hunch is correct.

Comment: I updated my post with a sample of the dataset. Thanks

Comment: Thanks, that confirms it. Factors aren't the appropriate data type here, since in this case they're shuffling your numbers out of order, leading to nonsensical plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the even-ish distribution (for what should be a clear positive correlation between "likes" and "shares") is a clue that the numeric data might have been inadvertently loaded as a factor. Another clue is that the x and y value only vary by the number of unique values, not by the range of the underlying numeric data. **We need to convert the levels of the factor (and not the values of the factor) to see the intended numbers. We can do this with something like `as.numeric(as.character(x))`**.

---

To give an example, suppose we had some linearly correlated data like this:

```
library(ggplot2); library(dplyr)
set.seed(42)
fake_data <- data.frame(x = runif(10000, 0, 1000000))
fake_data$y <- pmax(0, fake_data$x*rnorm(10000, 1, 2) + runif(10000, 0, 1000000))
ggplot(fake_data, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

If that numeric data were loaded in as factors (easy to do with `read.csv` if the term `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` isn't included), it might look more like this, not too dissimilar from the data in this question. The data here is being read as if it were character data, and then made into a factor which is ordered alphabetically, with "10000" before "2" because "1" comes before "2".

```
fake_data_factor <- fake_data %>%
  mutate(x = as.factor(as.character(x)),
         y = as.factor(as.character(y)))
```

The x and y values now have *values* related to their alphabetical order, different from their underlying *levels*. R uses the *values* to sort or to plot, and the x values with the lowest *values* in the new data have *levels* near 100,000 instead of near 0. In the table below, 100,124 in row 1 comes alphabetically earlier than 10,058 in row 8!

```
fake_data_factor %>%
  arrange(x) %>%
  head(8)
#                 x                y
#1 100124.688120559                0
#2 100229.354342446 289241.187250382
#3 100299.560697749 232233.101769741
#4 100354.233058169 814492.563551191
#5 100364.253856242 1183870.56252858
#6   100370.0227011 1224652.83777805
#7 100461.616180837 1507465.73704898
#8 10058.1261795014 604477.823016668

ggplot(fake_data_factor, aes(as.numeric(x),as.numeric(y))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

We can get back to the intended numbers by converting the factors to character (which extracts each one's level) and then converting those to numeric.

```
fake_data_factor %>%
  ggplot(aes(as.numeric(as.character(x)),as.numeric(as.character(y)))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. My plot looks much better now.